# How can I add GlassFish to my Netbeans Maven Java Application project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

I would like to use `org.glassfish.api.embedded` in my Java application so that I can add a web interface to it. I'm using Netbeans and I have set up a *Maven Java Application* project.

I'm pretty new to Java. I cannot figure out how to add GlassFish to my project. I tried to add various dependencies, but none of them had `org.glassfish.api.embedded` in them.

How can I add `org.glassfish.api.embedded` to my Java application in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupdId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupdId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

> GlassFish Server 3.1.2 in a single JAR, useful for embedded use.
>   Contains the full platform implementation (67 MB).

Or:

```
<dependency>
    <groupdId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupdId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

> GlassFish Server 3.1.2 in a single JAR, useful for embedded use.
>   Contains the Web Profile implementation (40 MB).

It should be available via Maven Central, so you don't have to configure any repository.

The only downside: the jars are quite big (40MB resp. 67MB).

Comment: I'm downloading the jar now. It being big isn't a problem.

Comment: It might become an issue if you plan to create a Swing or JavaFX application and distribute it with Java WebStart. Then your users will have to download this jar as well.

Comment: I'm writing bug-tracking software (as an installable server), so it won't be an issue.

Comment: The *glassfish-embedded-all* jar doesn't seem to have `org.glassfish.api.embedded`, but it does have `org.glassfish.embeddable`. Can I use that for running a web server inside of my application?

Comment: In this case I recommend to build your application with Java EE and deploy it to a GlassFish server instance, rather than trying to embed GlassFish.

Comment: Yes, please read the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24932/embedded-server-guide.htm